# String Compare Error

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, compare, immediate-window

if I type this into my Immediate Window

```
String.Compare("AA", "SA");
```

I get a result of 1

surely this is wrong? AA is less than SA so shouldn't it be -1?

I am running .NET 4

Comment: I get -1: http://rextester.com/WUDDT41321

Comment: That's what's confusing to me, I don't understand why it is returning the wrong result.

Comment: When possible, the application should use string comparison methods that accept a CompareOptions value to specify the kind of comparison expected. As a general rule, user-facing comparisons are best served by the use of linguistic options (using the current culture), while security comparisons should specify Ordinal or OrdinalIgnoreCase. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions.aspx)

Comment: Yes it was a culture issue, turns out in Danish there is a letter 'AA' in their alphabet which appears after 'SA'. It is to display a list in order for users so guess if they are use to that I will keep it the way it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Danish culture "AA" is treated as a single letter "Å" and alphabetically it comes after "Z".

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da-DK");
int comparision = String.Compare("AA", "SA", false, cultureInfo);
Console.WriteLine(comparision);
```

Result:

```
1
```

To get the result you want you can use invariant culture (or a specific culture that has the sort order that you desire):

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
int comparision = String.Compare("AA", "SA", false, cultureInfo);
Console.WriteLine(comparision);
```

Result:

```
-1
```

Comment: That was it! Checked my culture and it was set to Danish lol Thought I was going mad

Comment: Just wrote [this](http://rextester.com/CRK15034) to find all the cultures where it returned `1`